# cannot post a list item with a file using rest api

Tags: list, rest

I am able to post files into folder using rest...
but now I am trying to post files into a list and received

> {"error":{"code":"-1,
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ResourceNotFoundException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"Cannot
>   find resource for the request files."}}}',   cookies: [] }

I am trying to post using `https://site/_api/web/lists(guid'03a7f359-f263-4353-a491-504c2d06cd79')/items(add(overwrite=true, url='filename')`. Is the url the problem?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

The ListItemCollection does not have a files collection, so you cannot call the Add method. You can only add files to a document library by using a folder in you URL. Here is an example URL:

http://site/_api/web/lists(guid 'guid')/rootfolder/files/add/(url='whatever.png',overwrite=true)

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have loaded all the scripts that you need when you make your POST request. You can use the [SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff411788%28v=office.14%29.aspx) function.